# Incrementing and initializing multiple counters using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Please I need help with the use of streams to initialize counters while looping through a collection:

```
//Method containing the logic to be converted to streams

    int errorOnlyCount = 0;
    int warningOnlyCount = 0;
    int bothErrorAndWarningCount = 0;
    int successfulProcessedCount = 0;


for(ReportItem summaryReportItem: summaryReportItemList){
    Map<String, Integer> summaryReportItemMap = getTermErrorCount(summaryReportItem);

    if(summaryReportItemMap.get("errorCount").intValue() > 0 &&
            summaryReportItemMap.get("warningCount").intValue() == 0
    ){
        errorOnlyCount += 1;
    }

    if(summaryReportItemMap.get("errorCount").intValue() == 0 &&
            summaryReportItemMap.get("warningCount").intValue() > 0
    ){
        warningOnlyCount += 1;
    }

    if(summaryReportItemMap.get("errorCount").intValue() > 0 &&
            summaryReportItemMap.get("warningCount").intValue() > 0
    ){
        bothErrorAndWarningCount += 1;
    }

    if(summaryReportItemMap.get("errorCount").intValue() == 0 &&
            summaryReportItemMap.get("warningCount").intValue() == 0
    ){
        successfulProcessedCount += 1;
    }
}


//Method called from the logic above

private Map<String, Integer> getTermErrorCount(ReportItem summaryReportItem){
        int errorCount = 0;
        int warningCount = 0;

        if(summaryReportItem.getIsDuplicateItemError())
            errorCount += 1;
 
        if(summaryReportItem.getIsDescriptionWarning())
            warningCount += 1;

        Map<String, Integer> errorWarningCounterMap = new HashMap<>();
        errorWarningCounterMap.put("errorCount", errorCount);
        errorWarningCounterMap.put("warningCount", warningCount);

        return errorWarningCounterMap;
    }

//POJO with the string id and booleans variables

public class ReportItem {
        private String id;
        private boolean isMissingIdError;

        public ReportItem id(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        @Nonnull
        @JsonProperty("id")
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public ReportItem isMissingIdError(Boolean isMissingIdError) {
            this.isMissingIdError = isMissingIdError;
            return this;
        }

    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty("isMissingIdError")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    public Boolean getIsMissingIdError() {
        return this.isMissingIdError;
    }

    public void setIsMissingIdError(String id) {
        this.isMissingIdError = isMissingIdError;
    }
}
```

I was thinking of creating a stream for each if-block, but then how do I increment and initialize the counters.

Below is my code for the first counter's block.

```
 Stream<ReportItem> errorOnlyCountStream = summaryReportItemList.stream().filter(i -> (getTermErrorCount(i).get("errorCount").intValue() > 0 &&
                getTermErrorCount(i).get("warningCount").intValue() == 0));
```

Please, can someone help out with a snippet for the best approach?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: It may be helpful if you share the implimentation of your `ReportItem` class and  `getTermErrorCount` method

Comment: Thanks Pals. I have added the getErrorCount() method definition and more details. @Louis, I was thinking of doing one counter logic from a unique stream, sorry for the confusion. ReportItem is a simple POJO with setter/getter for string ID and boolean variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this all reasonably well from one stream.

```
Map<Boolean, Map<Boolean, Long>> results =
   summaryReportItemList.stream()
     .map(ThisClass::getTermErrorCount)
     .collect(
       Collectors.partitioningBy(
         map -> map.get("errorCount") > 0,
         Collectors.partitioningBy(
           map -> map.get("warningCount") > 0,
           Collectors.counting())));
int errorOnlyCount = results.get(true).get(false).intValue();
int warningOnlyCount = results.get(false).get(true).intValue();
int bothErrorAndWarningCount = results.get(true).get(true).intValue();
int successfullyProcessedCount = results.get(false).get(false).intValue();
```

From the particular structure of this code, it looks like you could eliminate the map conversion entirely and partition directly on `getIsDuplicateItemError` and `getIsDescriptionWarning`, but this is most similar to the code you've already written.

Comment: Wow @Louis, Streams is powerful. I am new to Streams and it took me a while to get my head round your solution. But, I think it makes sense to me now, just need to plug it into the code to replace the current logic. Thanks a lot.
Also, Eklavya your solution is cool and It will work as well.
Guys, thanks a lot.

Comment: Guys, I am trying to get the :
.map(ThisClass::getTermErrorCount) working, updated it to
.map(ReportItem::getTermErrorCount). But Java was not happy with the getTermErrorCount as the method expects a parameter i.e.  .map(ReportItem::getTermErrorCount(currentReportItemReference) )
I have not found any useful online ref so far.

Comment: `ThisClass` should be the class in which the static method `getTermErrorCount` is defined.

Comment: My schoolboy error. So, how do I pass the param to the getTermErrorCount method please?
 It's an instance method.

Comment: If it's an _instance_ method, then it should be `this::getTermErrorCount` instead.

Comment: Thanks the compiler hinted making it static. I will use the this construct. Does that implicitly use the current iteration object? i.e. this::getTermErrorCount = this::getTermErrorCount(currentItemInTheLoop). ?

Comment: `this::getTermErrorCount` is equivalent to `item -> this.getTermErrorCount(item)`, so yes.

Comment: Thanks a million, Louis. I really appreciate your value-adding time (:-